# Finding a substring within a string using an array?

Tags: list, python-3.x, substring

Trying to get my head around programming, I cannot work out why this doesn't work? Am I using "not" and "in" incorrectly?

I am trying to get the program to only print the characters that appear in both the strings. It correctly identifies them, but I can't get it to only print one set of the characters if there is more than one occurrence.

```
a = input("string1 :")
b = input("string2: ")
list1 = []

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i == j and i not in list1:
            list1.append([i])
            break

print(list1)
```

For example if you print the strings "alexander" and "alex" it will print the characters a, l, e, x, a, e

I know this current method only works if string1 is inputted as the main string, but I am just interested as to why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that instead of adding the common letter to the list1, you are adding a new list containing only the common letter to list1. At the end you have a list of lists. At the same time you are checking if a single letter is in the list of lists, which will be always false.

You should just add the common letter "i" to the list using append:

```
a = input("string1 :")
b = input("string2: ")
list1 = []

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i == j and i not in list1:
            list1.append(i)
            break

print(list1)
```

You could also just convert string a and b to sets and intersect them:

```
print set(a) & set(b)
```

Comment: Oh wow, thankyou! You helped me understand lists better. Very helpful, I can't believe it was that simple